# 403 Forbidden when accessing events using Google CalDAV

Tags: google-oauth, caldav

Stack: Python, `caldav` library.

I use OAuth2 for authentication and provide access token in all requests:

```
"Authorization": <access_token>
```

Scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events`

I get `403 Forbidden` on this request:

```
REPORT https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/caldav/v2/<calid>/events 403
```

But requesting calendars works as expected:

```
PROPFIND https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/<email%40gmail.com> 207
```

---

1. My first guess about the problem was invalid scope, but as I use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events` and grand all requested permissions during authentication, and can access calendars, so that doesn't seem to be the reason.
2. Next I thought that request method might cause the problem, but `REPORT` method is [supported](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) by Google.
3. Also I checked if access token is passed in headers in every request and that is not the reason either.
4. Access token is not stale.

---

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the scopes. After I replaced `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly` with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` I could access events.